# Spark Direct Streaming - consume same message in multiple consumers

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

How to consume `Kakfa topic messages` in multiple Consumers using `Direct Stream approach?`

Is it possible? Since Direct Stream approach doesn't have `Consumer Group` concept.

What happens, if i pass `group.id` as kafkaparams for the DirectStream method?  The below code works `with group.id` as Kafka Params also `without group.id`.

**Sample Code:**

```
val kafkaParams = Map(
  "group.id" -> "group1", 
  CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG -> sasl,
  ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
  ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
  "metadata.broker.list" -> brokerList,
  "zookeeper.connect" -> zookeeperURL
)

val dStream = 
  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
    ssc, kafkaParams, topicSet
  ).map(_._2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens, Sparks direct streaming approach doesn't take into account the group id parameter at all as it uses the lower level `SimpleConsumer`. You can't consume the same topic with different Spark direct approach streams. You can defer to the older receiver based approach which does utilize groups.