# Kafka exceptions when loading more than 1 consumer of the same group via spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I use Kafka's CreateDirectStream to create consumers from my spark streaming application.
when I load a single instance of my consumer app it works perfectly, however when I launch a second app with the **same consumer group**, one of the instances gets an exception within a few seconds: `...IllegalStateException: No current assignment for partition testTpc1-1`

My consumer code is fairly straight forward:

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.CreateDirectStream[String,String](
ssc,
PreferConsistent,
Subscribe[String,String](topics,kafkaParams)
)
```

I also have `enable.auto.commit` set to `false`

<s>How can I run multiple consumers of the same consumer group on a single kafka topic (with partitions)?</s>

Kafka ver 0.10
Spark ver 2.2
Scala ver 2.11

**UPDATE-EDIT:** Reading the answer here: [Spark Direct Streaming - consume same message in multiple consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155542/spark-direct-streaming-consume-same-message-in-multiple-consumers)
I see that `direct streaming` does **not** support multiple consumers of the same group.  I guess I need to find a different solution.
So my next question is - Does DirectStream offer any performance solution to compensate for the lack of ability to use multiple consumers of the group (i.e. doing the same work)?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of Spark is to allow you to parallelize execution on your data without "manual" balancing of load. The consumer groups are designed for the opposite case - you're scaling "manually" by adding new instances into the consumer group.

The question in reality is about scalability of your Spark application - you need to add more details on what kind of processing you're doing, what performance problems you have, how many partitions in your topic, etc.

Comment: Type of processing -> Reading json files from kafka, using spark sql, doing some simple calcs and writing result to hdfs files.  Number of partitions is really something I'm testing, I know best practices (n * num_of_brokers) where n=some int.

Comment: You need to profile your Spark code to see where the bottleneck occurs. Without code, etc. it's hard to suggest anything

Comment: thanks for your comments.  Currently I'm only starting to benchmark my code, moving from local to cluser env.  I wanted to try the Multi-Consumer approach when I realized `DirectStream` doesn't work this way, so it left me wondering how parallelism is implemented, and which params are available for me to "fine tune" it if at all.

Comment: When Spark is used the parallelism will depend on number of partition in topic, and then number of partitions created for data...